# Solve for a vector $x$ given $x'Ax=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand how to solve a standard matrix vector equation through matrix inversion

$$
Ax=b
\implies x=A^{-1}b
$$

where $x$ and $b$ are vectors and $A$ is an invertible matrix.

But how would we solve for $x$ if we have

$$
x'Ax=1
$$

Here $x'$ denotes the transpose of vector $x$, so the resulting value is a scalar, in this case 1. I'm not sure if there is a simple closed form solution.

Comment: Look up “Quadratic Form”

Comment: Apart from Benjamin's comment, try and work out what the equation means when $A$ is a diagonal matrix to get some intuition. For example, if $A=Id$, then you are looking at the unit sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there is not going to be a single solution but an infinite set of solutions along some surface. But, I'll show you the general strategy to identify this set in the nicest possible form. To keep things simple, I'll assume $A$ is real valued.

Given $A$, define the symmetric matrix $S=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$. Since $x^TAx$ is a scalar, it is equal to its transpose and we can make the following observation about $x^TSx$. $$x^TSx$$$$=\frac{1}{2}x^T(A+A^T)x$$$$=\frac{1}{2}x^TAx+\frac{1}{2}x^TA^Tx$$$$=\frac{1}{2}x^TAx+\frac{1}{2}(x^TAx)^T$$$$=x^TAx$$

So, it suffices to look at $x^TSx$. Since $S$ is symmetric, it can be written as $S=RDR^T$ for some rotation matrix $R$ whose columns are the eigenvectors of $S$ and a real diagonal matrix $D$ with the eigenvalues of $S$ along the diagonal. Therefore:

$$x^TSx=x^TRDR^Tx=(R^Tx)^TD(R^Tx)$$
Now, we rotate our coordinate system and choose our new basis such that $y=R^Tx$. This preserves the shape of the final set but changes its orientation in space. If $\lambda_i$ denotes the eigenvalues of $S$, the equation becomes

$$1=y^TDy=\lambda_1y_1^2+\lambda_2y_2^2+\dots+\lambda_ny_n^2$$

This is in general an $n-1$ dimensional surface whose orientation depends on the eigenvectors of $S$ and whose shape depends on the positivity/negativity of the eigenvalues. Even in two dimensions, there are several cases.

- If both eigenvalues are positive, the set is an ellipse. If they are also equal to each other, the set is a circle.
- If one eigenvalue is positive and one is negative, the set is a hyperbola.
- If one eigenvalue is positive and the other is zero, the set consists of two parallel lines.
- In any other case, the set is empty.